# How can I stop the password input field from changing its style when I toggle on using material icon?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

```
<div class="form-group mt-4 fake-input">
<mat-hint *ngIf=""></mat-hint>
   <input [type]="hide ? 'password': 'text'" formControlName="password" id="password" 
    type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/>
<mat-icon id="eye" matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
</div>
```

I'm building a login form that makes the password visible when the icon is toggled on and off. The images below show the display before and after the toggle. I have only just positioned the icon within the input field.

[image: after toggle]

Answer (score 0):

add  *autocomplete="new-password"* to input

```
<div class="form-group mt-4 fake-input">
<mat-hint *ngIf=""></mat-hint>
   <input [type]="hide ? 'password': 'text'" formControlName="password" autocomplete="new-password"
id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/>
<mat-icon id="eye" matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was repeating a mistake in my styling. I fixed it by changing

```css
  input[type=email],
  input[type=password]{
    position: relative;
    height: 2.2em;
    padding: 18px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: $lightPink;
    border-left: 2px solid $deepPink;
    font-family: Verdana;
    letter-spacing: 0.012em;
  }
```

To (styling without navigating to input type)

```css
  input {
    position: relative;
    height: 2.2em;
    padding: 18px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: $lightPink;
    border-left: 2px solid $deepPink;
    font-family: Verdana;
    letter-spacing: 0.012em;
  }
```

:

Thank you all for contributing.